# how to disable a label tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, tags

i need to create five labels using `<label>` tag in html. then when any one of the label is clicked all the other four labels must be disabled. i have searched through the google but could not find how to disable label tag. is there any way to do that .any suggestion......

```
<label for="u">username1</label>
<label for="u">username2</label>
<label for="u">username3</label>
<label for="u">username4</label>
<label for="u">username5</label>
```

Comment: Labels can't really *be* disabled. Do you mean "disappeared"?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by disabling a label.

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve. There's probably a better solution.

Comment: You should absolutely not do this. This is now how HTML is supposed to work, it's inaccessible to assistive devices and semantically completely wrong. Use `<option>`, it's specifically built for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Before looking at your example, I would have said:

> A label can't be disabled. One of the effects it has is to extend the click target of a form control, so you probably want to disable the form control instead.

However, for some reason, all your labels are associated with the same control (the one with `id="u"`), which suggests that you aren't using `<label>` correctly. It is possible to have multiple labels for a single control, but it doesn't look like you are doing that.

You should probably take a step back and describe the problem that you think disabling a label will solve.

Answer (score 6):

You can see in the source a whole solution using Javascript and CSS.
But if you want labels "look" like disabled you can use CSS this way:

**In HTML**

```
<label  class="disabled" for="u">username1 </label>
```

**In CSS**

```
label.disabled { color: #aaa; }
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I have a checkbox and a label, and when I disable the checkbox I want the label to have the same appearance of being disabled. Otherwise it's easy to miss that the checkbox is disabled. I think this is the same effect the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do would be to not only make it look disabled but also to disable any action on click of it. I would use the below code for this purpose:

**In HTML**

```
<label  class="disableLabel" for="u">username1 </label>
```

**In CSS**

```
.disableLabel {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You, cant disable the Labels. Instead u can set the Text property of the label to `""` when one label is clicked for the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `disabled` property in the `label` element doesn't work, you can apply it manually in DevTools. Programmatically, though, you can use the `setAttribute` method:

```js
dateLabelEl.setAttribute('disabled', isDisabled);
```

And this works as expected.

JavaScript is weird. (Though, technically speaking, this is the DOM API.)